# Greek text IE8 issue with CSS text-transform

Tags: internet-explorer-8, webfonts, uppercase, css

Have a site with Greek text, in it I have this div which i have applied the style `text-transform:uppercase`.

```
<div class="greek" style="text-transform:uppercase;">Υπηρεσίες</div>
```

*Lower case:*                **Υπηρεσίες**

*Transformed to upper case:* **ΥΠΗΡΕΣΊΕΣ**

So wat it does in IE8 is it shows the text in uppercase except for one letter **"ς"**

*so on IE8 it display it like:* **ΥΠΗΡΕΣΊΕς**

Well this works fine on all browsers (FF, Chrome, IE9, IE10, IE11) but not in IE8.

Well it transforms the **"σ"** to **"Σ"** but doesnot transform the **"ς"**

Does some one have any CSS solution for this one.?

Comment: This is a font issue, not so much css

Comment: If your site targets handheld devices, don't bother to fix it. If not, IE8 users are decreasing by the day and most of them are aware that some sites might not look the same as they have an "old browser".

Comment: @PellePenna: yeah true IE8 users are coming down, but for us we got to fix it as lot of our customers do use IE8 according to the analytics.

pstenstrm: well have u come across such a bug. I tried changing the font but it dint work..

Comment: If you can't fix it client side, try server side, there you for sure can solve it (ASP or PHP)

Comment: I kinda dint want to use a JS solution for it and put unnecessary load on the page. Thought would be good if there is some other fix for it. Like some font change or some css change.

Comment: I am seeing incorrect tonos render in IE9 and IE10 as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug/deficiency in the browser. By the specifications, [`text-transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-transform) must apply Unicode case mapping rules, which include mapping the final small sigma “ς” to uppercase sigma “Σ”. (They should *also* do uppercase to lowercase mapping in a manner that maps word-final “Σ” to “ς”, but that’s a different issue, and more complicated.) But some browsers still fail to do that.

There is nothing in CSS you can do about this. Client-side, what you could do is to have JavaScript code that fixes this by doing the conversion in content. But it is much better to do it server-side. Either write the content in all uppercase if you want it shown that way, or (if it comes from an external source), do the mapping using whatever server-side tools you are using.

Note that when you try to uppercase Greek text with CSS, you have other problems too. As the screen shot shows, the small iota with tonos “ί” has been transformed to capital iota with tonos “Ί”. This is not correct by Greek rules when uppercasing a word; the tonos (acute accent) should be omitted. Most browsers don’t do this right (Firefox does).

Answer (score 0):

I was about to ask the same question when I found the solution:

For most languages you can just slap `text-transform:uppercase` and it will work. For greek you have to [declare the language in the HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations), so you should add `lang="el"` to your div and it will work.

For example, while

```
<p>Διάβασμα του Καφέ</p>
```

becomes ΔΙΆΒΑΣΜΑ ΤΟΥ ΚΑΦΈ

```
<p lang="el">Διάβασμα του Καφέ</p>
```

gets correctly transformed to ΔΙΑΒΑΣΜΑ ΤΟΥ ΚΑΦΕ